# Error on Test coverage - Email service to create a new record

Tags: unit-test, apex-email-service

I have an email service that creates a new "training" record. the email body is broken down to populate several fields.

Class:

```
global class ProcessTraining implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();


   String[] emailBody = email.plainTextBody.split('\n', 0);

Training__c em;

String CertificationAttempts = emailBody[22].substringAfter(': ').trim();
String ScorePercent = emailBody[17].substringAfter(': ').trim();
String TimeSpent = emailBody[11].substringAfter(': ').trim();
String datecomp = emailBody[9].substringAfter(': ');
String TrainingName= emailBody[8].substringAfter(': ').trim();
String ContactEmail = emailBody[7].substringAfter(': ').trim();


String mm=datecomp.substringBefore('/');
String dd=datecomp.substringBetween('/','/');
String yy=datecomp.subStringAfterlast('/').trim();

date myDate=Date.newInstance(integer.valueOf(yy), 
     integer.valueOf(mm), 
     integer.valueOf(dd));

em= new Training__c (Message__c = email.plainTextBody);
em.Date_training_completed__c = myDate;
em.Number_of_certification_attempts__c = integer.valueof(CertificationAttempts);
em.Total_time_in_training_course__c =  decimal.valueof(TimeSpent);
em.Name = TrainingName;
em.Training_certification_score__c = decimal.valueof(ScorePercent);
Contact con = [SELECT id,email FROM Contact WHERE email = :ContactEmail];
em.Contact__c = con.id;

 insert em;


   return result;


} //close class

  }
```

Test Coverage:

```
@isTest

public class ProcessTrainingTest 
{ 
   static testMethod void TestinBoundEmail()
   {
       // create a new email and envelope object
       Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

       // setup the data for the email
      email.subject = 'Create Contact';
      email.fromAddress = 'someaddress@email.com';
      email.plainTextBody = 'email body\n2225256325\nTitle:\ntest:';


      // call the email service class and test it with the data in the testMethod
      ProcessTraining testInbound=new ProcessTraining ();
      testInbound.handleInboundEmail(email, env);



   }
   }
```

Whenever I run the test I get an error message:

> Error Message System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 22
>   Stack Trace Class.ProcessTraining.handleInboundEmail: line 16, column 1
>   Class.ProcessTrainingTest.TestinBoundEmail: line 20, column 1

Can you help me out in getting this class covered?

Comment: So it's failing to process the date? Your test email body doesn't appear to have any dates within it.

Comment: I tried to comment out the date section, and got the exact error...

Answer (score 1):

When the line below executes with the test data *'email body\n2225256325\nTitle:\ntest:'* it will only split the text into 4, so when you reference elements in the array such as **emailBody[9]** its giving you the out of bounds exception

```
String[] emailBody = email.plainTextBody.split('\n', 0);
```

Change your test so that it has the same data that would be in the email in a live system and also change your logic to be tolerant of emailBody being different sizes. Something like the code below would achieve this:

```
for(integer i=0 ; i < emailBody.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 22) {
         CertificationAttempts = emailBody[i].substringAfter(': ').trim();
    } 
}
```

Also consider moving the substringAfter logic to a method so that you [don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Eg create a method such as:

```
private String mySubstring(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
        return s.substringAfter(': ').trim()
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some debugging when you parse the email to see what that line really is ( `emailBody[??]` ).

ex:

```
String[] emailBody = email.plainTextBody.split('\n', 0);

for(integer i=0;i<emailBody.size();i++)
    system.debug('emailBody['+string.valueof(i)+'] = '+emailBody[i]);
```